# Should I use `inline` on heavily used functions?

Tags: c++, inline

I have a class `cnVector` that represents a point in 3 dimensional space.
Its operators + - * / are used intensively.
Their implementation is very short:

```
cnVector cnVector::operator + (const cnVector& v) const {
    return cnVector(
        x + v.x,
        y + v.y,
        z + v.z );
}
```

My question is, because this function is very short, should I inline it although its intensive use? or would it generate too much code when using it *that* much?

Comment: I mark functions this simple as inline.  It doesn't matter much though, if you tell the compiler to inline any that look good.  "Inline any suitable" on MSVC.  Dunno about GCC.

Comment: GCC passing [`-finline-functions`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html) will instruct it to automatically inline functions it thinks should be inlined.

Comment: My GCC (4.4.5) applies `-finline-small-functions` as a basic optimization (i.e. under `-O`/`-O1` and higher).

Comment: When you say "heavily used", be sure you know if you mean a) used in many places in the code, versus b) used enough times per second to account for >10% of the time. The latter argues for inlining, while the former doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you probably should. The good use case for the inline keyword in c++ is: small functions, heavily used.

See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w2887zk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Remember that using inline is never a guarantee, it just gives a hint to the compiler. I doubt inlining will actually increase executable size a lot, the function is very small in itself.
Calling the function is almost the same size as the function itself.

Answer (score 3):

Apply `inline` to **all** functions that you define in your header on namespace scope to avoid breaking the [One Definition Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_definition_rule). This, by the way, is completely unrelated to inlining, despite the keyword name. (Or put them inside an anonymous namespace.)

`inline` *also* gives a hint to the compiler to inline calls to said function, but as the comments have pointed out the compiler is quite capable of figuring that out by itself so the keyword isn’t really needed for that.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is perfectly capable of making a decision as to whether to inline a function or not depending on the chosen optimization profile.

You should inline a function if the compiler doesn't, and profiling with a realistic data set shows you're spending a significant amount of time in the function, the algorithm using said function is an efficient one, and if inlining it shows a speed improvement in a benchmark with said data set.

Answer (score 1):

If in doubt, compile it with and without inline and compare execution speed and size. The compiler usually offers a switch for profiling as mentionend above to see what the function call costs, measured in time,